# ASP.NET MVC - Visual Studio Publish Not Override Destination Web.Config

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new with ASP.NET MVC and just started playing around with it.  I am building a test project on my desktop and publish it on the Development Server (IIS).  After I published on IIS server and I received this error below:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS0433: The type 'System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TModel>' exists in both 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\test2_aspx_datatableeditable\8a6a3e30\832ace90\assembly\dl3\264e4d37\00038593_07d9cf01\System.Web.Mvc.DLL' and 'c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Mvc\v4.0_3.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Mvc.dll'
```

I then read different posts related to that error above and some suggested to remove the this statement below in the Web.Config file. After I removed the code below, it worked fine.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
```

Now, the problem is that every time I made some updates and publish from VS-2014, it overrides the web.config file, and then I have to remove the line of code in the web.config again in order for it to work.  I also tried to Right-Click the web.config file and set Build Action to None, but it didn't seem to work either.

I really don't want to go to the Output folder and keep remove the code line above in the web.config every time I publish it.  Is that anyway to NOT override the destination web.config only?

Thanks in advance,

Below is my simple web.config.  Please help with a sample code if web.config transform is a best option.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=152368
  -->

<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/> 
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/> 
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Helpers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <!--<add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />-->
        <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>

    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: look into web.config Transforms. Then you can maintain different versions of the config for each environment you deploy to.

Comment: Hi @ADyson, I am reading the web.config transform now and it seems complicated to me (not to you of course).  I've updated my post with the web.config I have, would you mind provide sample codes of how I make it work?  Thanks

Comment: @Milacay yes, web.config transforms are quite complicated. Have you considered simply taking the second reference out of your project's `bin` file? See here: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27522663/mvc-4-cant-fix-the-error-the-type-system-web-mvc-webviewpage-tmodel-exists-i)

Comment: The transform file simply contains some instructions to add, remove or change certain values in the base web.config. in your case it should only need to contain one entry instructing the problem line to be removed. Did you try it at all?

Comment: I removed the System.Web.Mvc from References folder and the project breaks now. I am still trying to add it back to the Reference...  :)  I see the System.Web.Mvc.dll under the Bin folder, but not in the References anymore. How do I add it back?

Comment: I was able to add it back the System.Web.Mvc.  If I remove the System.Web.Mvc from bin folder, it will generate this error `CS1705: Assembly '...., PublicKeyToken=null' uses 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

Comment: @ADyson, I tested on the https://webconfigtransformationtester.apphb.com/ site using this one entry `<add xdt:Transform="Remove" xdt:Locator="Match(assembly)" assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />` in the Web.Debug.config and it seems remove from Result.  But when I add that line in the Web.Debug.config my my VS2014, then Publish, the line didn't remove in web.config at the destination.  Any advice?

Comment: Which config profile are you using to publish the application? Normally you wouldn't publish in Debug mode, unless you're planning to do remote debugging. Anyway the Transform is only applied if the mode it belongs do (Debug in this case) matches the config profile specified in the Publish settings.

Comment: I put that "remove" entry in the Web.Release.config and it works now.  I am still wrapping my head around the web.config transform stuff.  So I can actually publish the Web.Debug.config?  Thanks a lot for helping.

Comment: You can if you want to publish to a site used for development debugging, yes. Just set your Publish profile to use the Debug mode.